# Using class methods in named_scope and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I may have painted myself into a corner.

In some of my rails (2.3.18) named_scopes I've used class methods to retrieve known rows from the database - for example status values.

However, when I try to use these with rspec, I think I've got a problem because the fixtures (I'm using FactoryGirl) haven't loaded before the app gets loaded - so I get an error when its parsing the named_scopes (I think).

For example:

```
named_scope :active_users, :conditions => [ 'status_id = ?', UserStatus.Active.id ]
```

When the user model is loading it gives an error to effect

```
app/models/user.rb:34: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4
```

which is the named_scope line.

```
user_status.rb
  def self.Active
    UserStatus.find_by_name('active')
  end
```

So I think I've got two questions:

1. Is this an abuse of named_scope and if so what would be a better way of writing it?
2. Is it possible to get rspec to load some key data into the database before it loads the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to answer my own question and am putting it here in case anyone else has the same issue.

To ensure that an attempt to access the database when the named_scope is parsed is avoided, I needed to wrap the :condition in a lamdba / proc as below

```
named_scope :active_users, lambda {{ :conditions => [ 'status_id = ?', UserStatus.Active.id ] }}
```

This now allows the application to be loaded, and then the data required for the tests to be loaded into the database ahead of the test as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Your named scope is written fine. You need to check output of UserStatus.Active.id. It should return array of ids. As per the naming convention if you have written method named 'Active' in UserStatus then it is wrong. It should be in lowercase.

Also I do not understand the use of id in => UserStatus.Active.id. Can you put this method here?

Comment: Thanks Ann. I've added the UserStatus method to the question to make it clearer what that is doing, and why I've written the named_scope the way I have

Comment: UserStatus.find_by_name('active') giving you nil. Make sure it returning you a record

Comment: Thats the problem Ann - no fixture data is being loaded before the application is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

UserStatus.Active must be giving you nil so 
UserStatus.Active.id giving you this error. Because id of nil is 4. Make sure you are getting a record in Active method